# How can I create multiple List with lambda expression?

Tags: filter, lambda, java-8, java-stream, predicate

I have a User with age property.
And in my method I have List. How can I split it to multiple List for another user like:

```
List<User> lt6Users = new ArrayList<User>();
List<User> gt6Users = new ArrayList<User>();
for(User user:users){
   if(user.getAge()<6){
      lt6Users.add(user);
   }
   if(user.getAge()>6){
      gt6Users.add(user);
   }
   // more condition
}
```

I just known 2 way with lambda expression:

```
lt6Users = users.stream().filter(user->user.getAge()<6).collect(Collectors.toList());
gt6Users = users.stream().filter(user->user.getAge()>6).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The code above is very poor for performance because it will loop through the list many time

```
users.stream().foreach(user->{
  if(user.getAge()<6){
     lt6Users.add(user);
  }
  if(user.getAge()>6{
     gt6Users.add(user);
  }
});
```

the code above is look like the code from start code without lambda expression. Is there another way to write code using lambda expression feature like filter and Predicate?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Collectors.partitioningBy(Predicate<? super T> predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-) :

```
Map<Boolean, List<User>> partition = users.stream()
                                          .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(user->user.getAge()<6));
```

`partition.get(true)` will give you the list of Users with ages < 6, and `partition.get(false)` will give you the list of the Users with ages >= 6.

Comment: Sorry if my example is not clear. I have comment in code block that it have more condition for another List like gt6andlt30User. How can we solve that problem

Comment: @gianglaodai `partitioningBy` is only suitable for breaking the List into two partitions by a single predicate. You could use `Collectors.groupingBy` to break the List into groups of Users having the exact same age (i.e. you'll get a `Map<Integer,List<User>>`, but perhaps that's not exactly what you want.

Comment: so in additional of my question. if i want to do something else than add element to List in each `if` block, is there anyway to do that?

Comment: @gianglaodai Can you be more specific? What something else might that be?

Comment: Simple like this: `if (user.getAge()<6){print('Hello baby'+user.getName())} if(user.getAge()>6{print('Hello boy'+user.getName())}`

Answer (score -1):

I've found a way to use lambda expression for this problem:
Write a method with Predicate:

```
public void addUser(List<User> users,User user,Predicate<User> p){
  if(p.test(user)){
    users.add(user);
  }
}
```

So the loop can be write like this:

```
users.foreach(user->{
  addUser(lt6Users,user,(User u)->u.getAge()<6);
  addUser(gt6Users,user,(User u)->u.getAge()>6);
  // more condition
});
```